# How is a mobile session defined in Google Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, session, google-analytics, mobile-analytics

I have 2 apps..Android and iOS and there are discrepancies between iOS and Android metric Avg Session Duration

- Android - 0:53 min
- iOS - 10:40 min

And Screen/Session metric is different too.

- Android - 7.62 screens
- iOS - 14.6 screens

It seems like there is error or difference in implementation..

In this docu https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en is description about "How is session defined", but only for desktop. Is session still "alive" when app is in background?